# Operation on numpy array in someone else code

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to understand a code written by someone else and i found this:

```
w &= (n == 2)  
w |= (n == 3)
```

Where w and n are both numpy arrays.
I have done some quick research on google but didn't find out what is it if some can tell me, I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: look at what e.g., `w += 3` does and see if that clarifies anything

Comment: ```&``` is a bitwise AND operator, not logical AND.
```|``` is the bitwise OR operator. Consequentially ```a &= b``` means ```a = a & b```. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: The ``&`` and ``|`` operators are binary "and" and "or", respectively. ``&=`` is an augmented assignment (like ``*=``) performing the operation and assigning the result to the initial name.

Comment: Yes i found out by testing my self but thank for the answers

Comment: if you have found than you may delete question or paste answer if you think it is good enough for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w` and `n` must be arrays of the same length. Then the operations are performed component-wise, so the first element of `w` will be compared with the first of `n`, the second of `w` with the second of `n` and so on.

`n == 2` will either return `True` or `False`, which are interpreted as `1` and `0`, respectively, when used with the [bitwise and/or operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). That means the result for `w & (n == 2)` will always be either `1` or `0`.

All operations are performed component-wise. So `w &= (n == 2)` will change the value at indices of `w` to `1` for which the last bit of the binary value of `w` at an index is `1` (in the case of an integer, that means the integer is odd) **and** the value at the same index in `n` is `2`. It will change the value to `0` for all other cases. Example:

```
w:            [1, 2, 3, 4]
w (binary):   [1, 10, 11, 100]
n:            [0, 2, 2, 3]
n == 2:       [False, True, True, False] (interpreted as [0, 1, 1, 0])
w & (n == 2): [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

In the same way, w |= (n == 3) works with the bitwise or; the binary representation in `w` ends with 1 **or** the value in `n` at the same index is `3`. `0` in all other cases:

```
w:            [1, 2, 3, 4]
w (binary):   [1, 10, 11, 100]
n:            [0, 2, 2, 3]
n == 3:       [False, False, False, True] (interpreted as [0, 0, 0, 1])
w | (n == 3): [1, 0, 1, 1] (1 and 3 are odd, and for the last index n has the value 3)
```